i want connect ssh as telnet (assign user after establishong ssh connection)
can anyone help me ..
i want to login to my router using ssh , but it uses ssh as telnet (entering username after establishing the connection).

ssh host-IP

i did it before but i forgot what was the ssh flags to do that, can anyone help

Is your router using Ubuntu? Which version?

You can find a complete list of the ssh client's command line flags in the manpage - probable the most applicable here are -l for the remote login name and possibly -p for the remote port number
